# Django - Unable to open database file (sqlite3.OperationalError)

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, sqlite

I am developing a small app with the django framework and when trying to serve it via Apache2 I get the following error:

> (sqlite3.OperationalError) unable to open database file (Background on
>   this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/e3q8)

My `settings.py` entry for the database looks like that:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3')
    }
}
```

The db file exists and has the following rights given by chmod:

```
root@myVPS:/var/www/lab# ls -l db.sqlite3
total 30236
-rwxrwxr-x 1 www-data www-data  3018568 Jul  1 22:14 db.sqlite3
```

The root folder `/var/www/lab`:

```
drwxrwxr-x 8 www-data www-data 4096 Jul 2 01:15 lab
```

I read that it might be a problem with the rights but I can't seem to find what I did wrong.

My Apache2 config file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        ServerName sub.domain.com
        ServerAlias sub.domain.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/lab
        <Directory /var/www/lab>
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride All
        </Directory>

        ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
        <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
                AllowOverride None
                Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

        # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
        # alert, emerg.
        LogLevel warn

        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        Alias /static /var/www/lab/static
        <Directory /var/www/lab/static>
                Require all granted
        </Directory>

        <Directory /var/www/lab/chatbot>
                <Files wsgi.py>
                        Require all granted
                </Files>
        </Directory>

        WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/lab/chatbot/wsgi.py
        WSGIDaemonProcess django_app python-path=/var/www/lab python-home=/var/www/lab/venv
        WSGIProcessGroup django_app

</VirtualHost>
```

I'm running Debian 8 with Python 3.5.3 and Django 2.2.3.

Comment: Did you check if `www-data` user have write permissions for `BASE_DIR`?

Comment: @abdusco permissions on `BASE_DIR` are `drwxrwxr-x` should be able to write. www-data is also assigned as folder owner

Comment: What’s the [Apache `User` directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_unixd.html#user) set to?  Can you add some logging to your Django settings module that records `os.getuid()` to show what user id is actually being used?

Comment: `os.getuid()` returns 33 which is the id for `www-data` as recorded in `/etc/group`

Comment: Try changing `WSGIDaemonProcess django_app python-path=/var/www/lab python-home=/var/www/lab/venv` to `WSGIDaemonProcess django_app python-path=/var/www/lab python-home=/var/www/lab/venv user=www-data group=www-data` and see if it helps

Comment: @TarunLalwani it's still not working

Comment: Are you using Docker?

Comment: This is almost certiainly a duplicate of [sqlite3.OperationalError: unable to open database file](//stackoverflow.com/q/7670289), which enumerates the [Django Wiki advice on how to use SQLite under mod_wsgi](https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/NewbieMistakes#DjangosaysUnabletoOpenDatabaseFilewhenusingSQLite3): Make sure the directory itself is writable (appears to be the case here), and that your /tmp/ directory is world writable.

Comment: You could **TEMPORARILY** set `BASE_DIR` to have world-writable permissions, so `777`, to be absolutely 100% certain it is not the permissions in this directory that are the cause. If not, it probably is your `/tmp` directory that's the issue. Make sure to reset the dir permission back to 775 afterwards.

Comment: @AndrejKesely No @MartijnPieters I changed ```BASE_DIR``` and the database to ```777``` but I still get the same error message. ```/tmp``` already has ```777``` permissions.

Comment: Verify that you are even finding the file by logging the name of the database and the result of `os.path.isfile(DATABASES['default']['NAME'])`.

Comment: @bigh_29 ```os.path.isfile``` returns ```True```

Comment: You have eliminated most of the things I thought might be the problem (wrong user, directories being off, sqlite failing to write one of its temp files). Multi-threading support in sqlite is one that you haven't touched. Assuming that is correct, then I don't have any great suggestions. If I were in your shoes, I would add a bunch of logging to see exactly where the thing is dying. I would add it by either creating my own django DB backend that inherits from the sqlite one, or by editing the source of sqlite driver. and sprinkling logging into the existing code. Good luck.

Comment: Actually, I would validate the sqlite file with the sqlite command line tool before embarking on that logging quest.

Comment: Did you try accessing the DB directly using `sqlite3` or similar package?
Do you have any password to this DB (you haven't wrote a user/password fields in the example above)?

Comment: @Gabsii, can you provide a minimal setup in a repo with a Vagrantfile or something? This is a hard to solve without experiencing it

Comment: Does it run from `python manage.py shell` and from `python manage.py dbshell`? Does migrations run?

Comment: Is `manage.py` and `db.sqlite3` in the same location?